# cakephp with oracle: no group by?

Tags: oracle, cakephp, dbo

Greetings,

I'm trying to use the 'group' parameter for a find using CakePHP.

The dbms is oracle and to my surprise it didn't work (no group by in the query).

Example:

```
$this->User->find('all', array('group' => 'id'));
```

The query returned:

```
select * from users User where 1 = 1;
```

digging around the source code at the DboOracle::renderStatement() I found this:

```
return "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table} {$alias} {$joins} {$conditions} {$order} {$limit}";
```

I was surprised not seeing a {$group}, so I look around and found out that some of the dbo_ files do actually have {$group} included in the query, for example dbo_source.php

```
return "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table} {$alias} {$joins} {$conditions} {$group} {$order} {$limit}";
```

Does this mean that cake doesn't support group by statement on oracle? Or is there a workaround that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem that was recently fixed. Check [this link](http://code.cakephp.org/tickets/view/98)